# What fruit/nut/berry grows in mottled sunlight on a climbing structure?

Tags: fruits, shade, trellis, berries

Location: Arizona

I currently have a [dying dragon fruit on a climbing structure](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16248/what-does-mesquite-tree-sap-have-that-possibly-makes-it-a-good-fertilizer-for-dr) that I am going to replace. Given that this location is in mottled sunlight and has a pre-established climbing structure I'm looking for something different to replace it with that would need and benefit from those 2 items. What are my options?

So far I've identified a kiwi fruit. I feel that there must be a ton more available...

Answer (score 4):

You could [train some grapevines](http://www.fassadengruen.de/eng/uw/climbing_plants/uw/grapevine/grapevine/training/vertical-cordons.htm) to grow on those. I'm not sure if there's enough sun.

If you count rose hips as fruit, you could grow climbing rose bushes.

There are lots of annual fruiting plants that climb, but they don't necessarily need to do so. For instance, a lot of cucurbits climb. Shark Fin Melon might be okay. It grows leaves pretty well on low light, anyway, and it climbs. The leaves are edible, too. They may be perennials in climates without cold winters.

Comment: Shark Fin Melon doesn't clime as much as I once thought. It can clime, if it wants to, though. You might try Kiwano, Suyo Long cucumber, Rattlesnake pole beans and such. Shark Fin melon doesn't fruit well in high heat and long days, either.